Exact Interpretation of IPv4 Routing Table
I was hoping to get help on interpreting my routing table. This is not a nestat output but should look familiar enough. I realize that the table is saying that if any destination addresses match an address within left column, then it gets routed through the gateway shown within the right column. Default gateway includes addresses excluded from the list. But questions still remain.
default 192.168.0.1 UGSc
1.0.0.1 192.168.0.1 UGHWIi
1.1.1.1 192.168.0.1 UGHWIi
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHWIi
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHW3I
169.254 link#8 UCS
192.168.0 link#8 UCS
192.168.0.1/32 link#8 UCS
192.168.0.1 MAC UHLWIir
192.168.0.100/32 link#8 UCS
IP 192.168.0.1 UGHWIi
224.0.0/4 link#8 UmCS
224.0.0.251 MAC UHmLWI
255.255.255.255/32 link#8 UCS


What does the flag "3" represent? The others I understand.
What is the purpose of indicating that a destination address or subnet goes through a Link Layer gateway, such as link#8 instead of using a MAC address?
Does the fact that I have specific IP addresses routing to my router's gateway mean that I have routing rules hardcoding these routed values? Why be explicit and not include them under the default category?
I recognize all the Mac addresses, where 74.fe.ce.c.ad.bd is the LANs gateway, but I don't recognize the MAC address of the multicast of 224.0.0.251.
Does the multicast address signify that all traffic network traffic is being advertised to subscribers over mdns.mcast.net (224.0.0.251)?

Note: IP represents an IP address that I omitted for privacy. Likewise, the MAC address has been omitted.


What is the purpose of indicating that a destination address or subnet goes through a Link Layer gateway, such as link#8 instead of using a MAC address?

No, it indicates that there is no gateway, and that the packets can be directly delivered to the destination host's MAC address (which would be resolved via ARP as usual), instead of any gateway's MAC address.
For example, 192.168.0 link#8 means that a packet meant for 192.168.0.55 would cause an ARP query for 192.168.0.55 itself, whereas 1.1.1.1 192.168.0.1 means that a packet meant for 1.1.1.1 would cause an ARP query for 192.168.0.1 instead.

Does the fact that I have specific IP addresses routing to my router's gateway mean that I have routing rules hardcoding these routed values? Why be explicit and not include them under the default category?

In this specific case, unknown reasons. Sometimes, though, it is done to override a possible "in-between" route – e.g. at home I have an explicit 10.147.0.0/16 route through my default gateway, and its purpose is to override an "10.0.0.0/8 via VPN" route whenever I connect to my workplace VPN.

I recognize all the Mac addresses, where 74.fe.ce.c.ad.bd is the LANs gateway, but I don't recognize the MAC address of the multicast of 224.0.0.251.

It's a multicast group address. All multicast IP addresses have an algorithmic mapping to an Ethernet 'group' MAC address (01-00-5E-xx-xx-xx for IPv4 or 33-33-xx-xx-xx-xx for IPv6).

Does the multicast address signify that all traffic network traffic is being advertised to subscribers over mdns.mcast.net (224.0.0.251)?

No, it signifies that traffic sent to this group is delivered to all subscribers of that group.
(Group 224.0.0.251 is used specifically for mDNS, which macOS calls "Bonjour" – it's the primary LAN device discovery mechanism in macOS.)


Do you have any clue on what the flag of 3 indicates? It only appears when specific IP addresses are used for the destination address, ones that I don't recognize.
Then what does it mean when there is an explicit MAC address under gateway instead of link#x or an IP address? 5. If it signifies traffic sent to this group is delivered to all subscribers of that group, then which traffic is "traffic"? I can't tell by the table how traffic may be routed via multicast.


1,2) Both things are specific to your OS – your example output looks very BSD-like, so I'm guessing macOS or FreeBSD? – but from what I remember, the 'numeric' flags don't have a single defined meaning. If macOS has a specific meaning for flag 3, I don't know it. As for the MAC address as gateway... I believe it's another BSD-ism: that is, merging the ARP cache into the routing table. (After all, the entire purpose of the 'gateway' field is to eventually get resolved to a MAC address, like how an IP gateway just means "resolve this to a MAC address via ARP and deliver packets there".)


There is not much to it – any IP packets that are sent to the group's address (i.e. IP destination = 224.0.0.251) become "multicast traffic". If you open Wireshark and then try to ping asdfg.local, you'll see that most mDNS packets have 224.0.0.251 (or the IPv6 equivalent, ff02::fb) as their destination.

